# how to implement Bootstrap tabs for each item of Ember's list-view?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using [Ember's](http://emberjs.com) [list-view](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view) to show a list of items and I wanted to implement a [Bootstrap tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to show each item's details, however, I can't figure how to do this elegantly in Ember. Here's what I've done so far:

**Javascript:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var data = [{title: 'Tab#1', body: 'Tab#1\'s content', desc:'description1'},
            {title: 'Tab#2', body: 'Tab#2\'s content', desc:'description2'},
            {title: 'Tab#3', body: 'Tab#3\'s content', desc:'description3'},
            {title: 'Tab#4', body: 'Tab#4\'s content', desc:'description4'},
            {title: 'Tab#5', body: 'Tab#5\'s content', desc:'description5'},
            {title: 'Tab#6', body: 'Tab#6\'s content', desc:'description6'},
            {title: 'Tab#7', body: 'Tab#7\'s content', desc:'description7'},
            {title: 'Tab#8', body: 'Tab#8\'s content', desc:'description8'},
            {title: 'Tab#9', body: 'Tab#9\'s content', desc:'description9'},
            {title: 'Tab#10', body: 'Tab#10\'s content', desc:'description10'}];

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() { return data; }
});

App.MyListComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  selectTab: function(name) {
    this.$("a[data-toggle='%@']".fmt(name)).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    this.$("a[data-toggle='%@']".fmt(name)).parent().addClass('active');
    this.$("a[data-toggle='%@']".fmt(name)).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.tab-content').children('div').removeClass('active');
    this.$("a[data-toggle='%@']".fmt(name)).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.tab-content #'+name).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

as you can see, the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) selector is kinda silly, but it works (I'm sure there's a far more efficient and prettier selector!)

**HTML: Handlebars + Bootstrap:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember + Bootstrap Tabs + List-View</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.3.1/ember.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/list-view/list-view-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#ember-list items=content height=800 rowHeight=100}}
      {{my-list item=this id=this.id}}
    {{/ember-list}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-list">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row margin-bottom-10">
    <div class="tab-v1">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="home" {{action "selectTab" "home"}}>Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="profile" {{action "selectTab" "profile"}}>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#description" data-toggle="description" {{action "selectTab" "description"}}>Description</a></li>
      </ul>                
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
          {{item.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
          {{item.body}}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="description">
          {{item.desc}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I didn't want to implement routeable tabs and do realize that I cannot preserve the state of the user interaction with the implementation above, however, I'm not meant to do so in this part of the application.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jawuvuko/1) of the code above to see it in action.

How to replace the jQuery part so that this is purely Ember? Is there a better to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: So.... what's your question?

Comment: @gravityplanx I've edited the post to better outline the question.